# share parent TRIGGER between INHERITS childs Postgresql 9

Tags: postgresql

```
create table parent(...);

create table child1(...)
inherits parent;
create table child2(...)
inherits parent;
create table child3(...)
inherits parent;
```

I want create a trigger for 'parent' and when I insert on child1 or child2 or child3 this trigger must automatically executed.
but seems didn't work, I must create a trigger for each child.
any solution for postgresql 9 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a trigger for each child table.

The maintenance burden is mitigated however by the fact that all triggers can point to the same function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 AFTER INSERT ON child1 FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigproc();

CREATE TRIGGER trig2 AFTER INSERT ON child2 FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigproc();
...
```